# Permissão para arquivo PHP utilizando AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, file-permission

Tenho um sistema que faz solicitações POST para arquivos .php no servidor por AJAX e eles me retornam dados do banco de dados para trabalhar no JS. Todos os arquivos .php estão em uma mesma pasta no servidor.

Eu gostaria de saber qual o melhor nível de permissão que eu devo setar para a pasta/arquivos visando permitir a requisição somente por AJAX, caso seja possível, ou o mais perto disso.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo usar esse header pra dar permissão quando preciso acessar por ajax, no caso do * pode setar a origem que tu quiser

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```